# LINE sharing plugin on Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

Angular5 Newbie here. In my blogging application, I would like to share an article on LINE. I have gone through [LINE official documentation](https://social-plugins.line.me/en/how_to_install#lineitbutton), but it gets failed during the build.

Then, I tried [NG2-social-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-social-share), but getting an error like:

> Unexpected value 'Ceiboshare'in ng2-social-share.d.ts

Any pointers would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CeiboShare package` is support upto for Angular 2 version. As this package is not updated for latest version of Angular we did social sharing manually.
Here is my component.html

component.ts

```
facebookShareUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=&t=';
shareWithLine() {
  console.log(document.URL);
  window.open('https://lineit.line.me/share/ui?url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL));
  return false;
}
```